# Setting value to ComboBoxs item #C

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm trying to set values on items in combobox, but everytime I try so I get the result 'null'. Am I defining the value wrong or am I trying to get the value in a wrong way?

```
// Setting the value
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Ime FROM Unajmljivaci WHERE Aktivan = 0";
conn.Open();
using (var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
         cmbUnajmljivaci.Items.Add(new { Id = reader["Id"].ToString(), Ime = reader["Ime"].ToString() });
    }
    cmbUnajmljivaci.ValueMember = "Id";  // <---
    cmbUnajmljivaci.DisplayMember = "Ime";
}

//Retrieving the value
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SifraUnajmljivca", Convert.ToString(cmbUnajmljivaci.SelectedValue));
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? Are you getting any error on cmbUnajmljivaci.Items.Add statement?

Comment: @TheShooter I'm not getting any error, it just saves 'null' instead of the value I want.

Comment: use SqlDataAdapter

Comment: @sebingel WinForms

Comment: @jayvee Doesn't SqlDataAdapter return a single row?

Comment: You mean combobox has as many null items as rows fetched by data reader?

Comment: Here's the thing: the combobox does have items that are named by the 'cmbUnajmljivaci.DisplayMember = "Ime";', and I can retrieve that DisplayMember with 'sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unajmljivac", Convert.ToString(cmbUnajmljivaci.Text));', but I can retrieve the ValueMember, which is 'Id'.

Comment: @L.Havrlisan No. Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING"))
            {
              DataSet ds = new DataSet();
              SqlCommand sqlCmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
              sqlConn.Open();
              SqlDataAdapter SQA_DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
              SQA_DataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Ime FROM Unajmljivaci WHERE Aktivan = 0", sqlConn);
              SQA_DataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Table");
              if (ds != null)
                if (ds .Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                  cmbUnajmljivaci.ValueMember = "Id";
                  cmbUnajmljivaci.DisplayMember = "Ime";
                  cmbUnajmljivaci.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                }
              sqlConn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Could use some explanation to go with the code dump

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the data source of the combobox.

Comment: Can you give me a bit more detailed answer please? I don't know how do you mean to set the data source.

Comment: cmbUnajmljivaci.DataSource = <your data source may be an IList>;

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the Value like this:

```
dynamic dyn = cmbUnajmljivaci.SelectedItem;
string s = dyn.Id;
```

Or even inline like this:

```
//Retrieving the value
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SifraUnajmljivca", Convert.ToString(((dynamic)cmbUnajmljivaci.SelectedItem).Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code for Reference to your problem,

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Rows.Add("0", "Item1");
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "Item2");
```

For inserting the item with specified index you need to use the below code

```
 //Insert the item into the collection with specified index
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]);
            string name=row["Name"].ToString();
            comboBox1.Items.Insert(id,name);

        }
```

Always **index** should **start** from **0 (Zero).**

**Easy way** to add values to combobox

```
comboBox1.DataSource=dt;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
```